# How to set favicon for IE?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, favicon

I am setting favicon for my website and can't make IE to work. I am using IE9 and the website is on internal test server. It works fine on Chrome, FF, Safari.

I have this line on Master page header. I also tried to put on page level.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

favicon.ico is in root folder. It is generate from [this website](http://www.favicon.cc/).

I have cleared cache, deleted browsing histories, restarted IE and click on refresh button several times.

There are many people with same problem but I have tried all sort but still no joy.

But all the popular websites work fine on IE so what I am wondering is how did they do that?

UPDATE:

I also tried putting absolute URL. Didn't work.

Wonder if i need to set anything on IIS?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918384/favicon-not-showing-up-in-address-bar-in-ie9-yet-is-displayed-there-in-all-oth

Comment: If you have the favicon.ico in the root folder, you don't need to specify anything else. So, the href to the icon is not important. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Comment: @bdoshi Thanks .. but it's not duplicate coz I have seen that post and tried that and didn't work

Comment: @David- I already have my favicon.ico in the root folder wonder why didn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this ico file (for test purpose) http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico

if it works then there is an issue with the ico file, otherwise remove this `type="image/x-icon"` .