# Favicon won't show in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, favicon

I am struggling for a long time to display a favicon in IE.
This is the code which is placed right after the opening of the head tag.

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.ecpre.cz/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.ecpre.cz/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about other browsers? Opera, Firefox, Chrome etc. Does it work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918384/favicon-not-showing-up-in-address-bar-in-ie9-yet-is-displayed-there-in-all-oth

Did you see this post ?

Comment: It works everywhere except in IE.

Comment: @Defoncesko I can see the post, but the answer is to put the absolute path and i already have it....

Answer (score 0):

It is because of "security" and "cleverness" of IE.
Try to put favicon.ico to your site root and make link to look like this

<link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon"/>

And additionally convert it to png and put favicon.png to the site root as well.

Comment: What do you mean? It is on the root... (www.ecpre.cz/favicon.ico)