# Why does IE uses the image in rel="icon" instead of rel= "shortcut icon" when i create a shortcut of a page?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

This is the code i used to declared which image to use as a page icon and which one to use as a desktop icon. Am i missing something?

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/src/images/desktop_favicon.ico" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/src/images/page_favicon.png">
```

Is it even possible to have a icon for the webpage and another for desktop?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918384/favicon-not-showing-up-in-address-bar-in-ie9-yet-is-displayed-there-in-all-oth

Comment: @diedie2 the problem isnt about making it appear in the address bar. The problem is when i create a shortcut of the page on my desktop using ie11 it uses page_favicon.png instead of desktop_favicon.ico

Comment: I noticed, but the accepted answer suggets you should use absolute path and not a relative one. The other (large) answer talks about the size of the icon, maybe that could be an issues to?
And the reason IE uses icon and not shortcut could be fallback, not sure though

Comment: Already tried both of the suggestions , but it still uses the icon declared on the rel="icon" tab, when i create a shortcut on my desktop. I dont even know i why IE would even bother creating a shortcut when we already have bookmarks.. T_T